# How to send an initial message using ServiceConnection?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-service-binding

I have an android service, which is connected to a service connection. Upon initialization, I'd like to send a single String, for example "test message" to the Service connection. How would I do this?

This is my `Service` class:

```java
public class ExampleService extends Service {
    private final IBinder iBinder = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler(this)).getBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return iBinder;
    }
}
```

This is my `ServiceConnection` implementation:

```java
private ServiceConnection myService = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        Log.i("exampleService", "Binding Connect");
        messenger = new Messenger(iBinder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        messenger = null;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ServiceConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection) monitors the state of the connection to the service, as opposed to communicating information to the service. To communicate with the service, you need to use the `binder` that is passed as an argument to the [`onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection#onServiceConnected(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.IBinder)) callback.

In your code sample, you are using a `Messenger` to perform communication instead of directly interacting with the binder. A [`Messenger`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger) is:

> a simple wrapper around a Binder that is used to perform the communication

Sample code that does what you are asking:

```java
public class MyService extends Service {
    // if there are a lot of options, use an enum; its not 2012 anymore and devices have 4GB+ of memory
    public static final int MSG_HELLO = 1;


    private class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case MSG_HELLO:
                    final String stringMessage = (String) message.obj;
                    Toast.makeText(MyService.this.getApplicationContext(), "MyService: " + stringMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                default:
                    return;  // message not understood, ignore
            }
        }
    }

    final private Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return messenger.getBinder();
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String HELLO_MESSAGE = "hello originating from MyActivity";


    private Messenger messenger = null;

    private final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            messenger = new Messenger(iBinder);

            // send a HELLO message immediately when connected
            final Message message = Message.obtain(null, MyService.MSG_HELLO, HELLO_MESSAGE);

            try {
                messenger.send(message);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                messenger = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            messenger = null;
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
    }
    
    // rest of implentation...
}
```

For a more detailed example of how to work with `Messenger`, see the [Remote Messenger Service Sample](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#remote-messenger-service-sample).

A couple notes:

1. If you are communicating with a local service (i.e. the service is in the same process as the activity), I recommend not using messenger as this will make things more complicated than necessary. Instead, you should create a subclass of [`Binder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder) that has a method which returns the instance of the service. See the [Local Service Sample](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#local-service-sample) for an example.
2. Make sure every `bindService(...)` has a corresponding `unbindService(...)` and vice versa. For example, if you call `bindService(...)` in `onCreate()`, then call `unbindService(...)` in `onDestroy()`.
3. Regardless of whether the service is local or remote, be aware of memory leaks. `IBinder` instances *may* stay in memory beyond the lifecycle of the component that is containing it, potentially until the process is destroyed; this can cause a severe memory leak. If you subclass `Binder` inside of an Activity or Service class, then use a static inner class, as opposed to a non-static inner class which will have an implicit reference to the Service or Activity. If you need a reference to a context or lifecycle aware component, then use a [WeakReference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference). The proper way to deal with this is outside the scope of this question. For related posts, see:

- [Memory leaks found when Local Binder has a reference to Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733538/memory-leaks-found-when-local-binder-has-a-reference-to-service)
- [LocalService and LocalBinder leak memory in Android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63787707/localservice-and-localbinder-leak-memory-in-android-10)
- [Android service-binder leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299472/android-service-binder-leaks)